# Generic approach to finding index of element

Tags: haskell, predicate, fold, monoids

There have been some major changes in base library, so I'm wondering whether today idiomatic solution would involve `fmap`, `Maybe`, `Monoid`, `First`, `Foldable` and maybe other classes.

I figured I would need to `fold` a complex structure of a `Monoid` with `zip [1..]`, `First`, `a -> Bool` and `Maybe`, but couldn't find obvious way to compose these things together.

Also, I suspect most of this code is in libraries. I'm just not sure whether (or how many) `newtype` wrappers would I need to compose classes to get a structure I need.

Comment: Sounds like `findIndex p . toList`.

Answer (score 0):

Zeta's comment is right. You can just call `toList` and then find the element in that. But supposing we didn't want to do this, how could we do it using monoids?

Here's one approach

```
data FirstTrue = FT Int Bool deriving Show

instance Monoid FirstTrue where
   mempty = FT 0 False
   FT n b `mappend` ~(FT n1 b1)
      | b = FT n True
      | b1 = FT (n + n1) True
      | otherwise = FT (n + n1) False

findIndex p t = let (FT i b) = foldMap (\x -> FT 1 (p x)) t
                in if b then Just i else Nothing
```

I don't think that you can do it in this generality and build it just out of `Foldable` and existing `Monoid` instances, as the types of compositions we have don't let you "cross over" the logic from the two conjoined monoid types (here the `Count` monoid and the `Any` monoid).